# Jquery and responsive design don't behave as expected when resizing browser

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, cross-browser

I'm trying to implement a responsive design that switches between a nav menu and a nav button at breakpoint 700px. 
For this i have two things :

Media queries

```
@media screen and (min-width: 700px)
{
    #main-nav
    {
        display: block;
    }

    #navButton
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

A simple jQuery script to close the menu when it is open and the window is resized.

```
// Fixing window resize bugs
$( window ).resize( function ()
{
    if ( $( window ).width >= 700 )
    {
        $( "#navButton" ).css( "display", "none");
    }
    else if ( $( window ).width < 700 )
    {
        $( "#navButton" ).css( "display", "block");
        $( "#menu-buttons" ).css( "display", "none");
    }
});
```

The problems arise when i am resizing the browser window.
It switches between the two layouts perfectly well on all my Mac browsers (Chrome 45, Firefox 41 and Safari 8) but it doesn't work on windows browser (IE 11 and Firefox 41 tested so far).
When the window innerWidth is between 700px and 716px, both nav and button are on screen at the same time.
One workaround is to replace `css( "display", "none");` with `css( "visibility", "hidden");` in the script but unfortunately, it creates other problems...

If anyone has any info about this problem, please let me know.

EDIT : Issue resolved by using the keyword "!important" in the media query.

Comment: Why use jQuery at all? This can be achieved in CSS alone

Comment: I'm using a basic JQuery animation somewhere else to change the menu button into a list of buttons. It creates some inline styles that i can't override in the CSS.

Comment: Could you not use `!important` in your CSS?

Comment: Good point, i'll give it a go. Thanks for suggesting this.

Comment: Adding the '!important' keyword in the media query fixed the problem. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by adding !important in the media query.